# Wordpress: How can I add tabs into page?

Tags: html, wordpress

I want to add tabs with links to other pages just above the page title.

For example, I have page named "Tab1", just above the title I want to have two links, one is "Tab1", second is "Tab2" - which leads to "tab2.html".

In simple words, I need to add a piece of HTML-code above the "entry-content" for a specific page in Wordpress.

How can I do that? Is there a plugin for adding tabs for pages? (I've tried to search, but haven't found anything) Or maybe a way to modify "content-page.php" in theme folder, so the HTML-code for tabs would be displayed only on a specific page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If anyone is interested, I found out a very simple solution for my case - the custom page. You can create a your-custom-page.php and insert any HTML-code in there, and there are even Wordpress plugins to do that kind of stuff. Good luck :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin should do the trick. You just have to set up your menus manually.

[Menu Per Pages Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-per-pages/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use jQuery UI Tabs, it's a very simple solution to creating tabs: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: I actually need tabs outside the post and the tabs should be external links to my other pages (SEO needs). Anyway, thank you for the response.